# How are asteroid belts and exploration sites generated?

Tags: eve-online

Are asteroid belts and exploration sites always consistent within a system? Or do they change from time to time.

Specifically about exploration sites, are there guaranteed to always be exploration sites in each system? e.g. if I use my scanner probes and find nothing, is that just because my skill isn't high enough - or do some systems just not have exploration sites sometimes?

And specifically about asteroid belts, do they change what types of asteroids exist within the system? Or do asteroid fields change up their composition - or sometimes switch to ice fields?

Comment: As newbie I would love to know the answer to this. Last week (Friday) I made 40 million in one night exploring, I found a ton of sites. Since then I haven't found anything other than LADAR, grav, and wormholes. So frustrating! what was I doing right last week?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asteroid belts do not change, they are simply refreshed every downtime. (May be different in Sov nullsec with [Ore Upgrades](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Ore_Prospecting_Array_1)). They *never* change to ice belts.

Exploration sites are not guaranteed to be in a system at any point in time. I believe there are X number of sites per constellation ( or region ) at any one point in time.

Outside of sovereign nullsec ( with infrasture hub upgrades), players have little control over exploration sites, other than spawning them ( which will start the de-spawn timer ) and running them ( which de-spawns them rather quickly ).

Comment: In Nullsec, Belts don't change either. However, each place in the belt can be taken by any sort of ore that is approperiate for the sec status of the system. A Veldspar Asteroid on one position can be a Scordite Asteroid the next day. Hidden Belts spawn when you have those upgrades in nullsec and respawn instantly when mined out completly (not wise in moderate and small grav site). There are different hidden belts and for each level you get 1. At level 2, a moderate AND a small belt spawn, at 3 a large gets *added* and so on. At higher industry levels, profession sites get a higher chance.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to user28015 in the above, the rocks in belts do not change period.  The same ore type will respawn if it is popped in the same location every time.  Even with the IHub upgrades, the rocks will just get bigger, and 'special' belts will spawn (able to be scanned down), never change the type of ore that are in them.

> Popping an asteroid doesn't affect regeneration. When you mine an asteroid down, whether it be to a pebble or nothing at all, its ore gets respawned elsewhere in the EVE world. It will regenerate in your own system when it's depleted elsewhere, though due to the mechanics of the regeneration (which I can't go into) it may take a while for the asteroid to resume its former size. There's no rhyme or reason to how quickly it'll respawn; it depends completely on how much ore of that type is mined elsewhere, and where in the respawn order your belt happens to land.

<sup>- [GM]Abraxas</sup>